# calculate date time by given days

Tags: php, sql

I have a form where user have to enter how many days example user enter for 2 days and it will deduct 2 days back.the result will looks like this

```
Current Date: 2012-02-10 
Last date: 2012-02-08
```

the time will be set every 11:59pm for each duration.because from this calculation i have to find the data from sql that match with the duration time...

```
Current Date: 2012-02-10 
Last date: 2012-02-08
List data xyz from the date is 30 times
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like `echo date("Y-m-d 23:59:59",strtotime("-2 days"));` Just make that "2" a variable from what the user types in and make sure they use a integer. Not sure if thats what you are looking for or a different question hard to tell.

Comment: thanks it give me idea how to structure it..but how in case user will pick any days..not just in 2 days...depends on what user enter...?

Comment: $days = abs(intval($_POST['days']));

`echo date("Y-m-d 23:59:59",strtotime("-{$days} days"));`

The abs() would force a positive number since we manually are adding the negative number in later so this would only work for going backwards in time, but if that's the only direction you are going then that should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
$now = $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"];
$2daysago = $now - 60 * 60 * 24 * 2;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $2daysago);
```

Comment: Why not use `$2daysago = $now - 172800;` to save doing the calcualtion every time?

Comment: Because `60 * 60 * 24 * 2` is easier to read? If you're worried about performance set up a PHP cache like memcached or APC.